# no ASP.Net Core Template in New ASP.Net Core Web Application screen Visual Studio 2017

Tags: templates, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm following a tutorial in developing .Net Core application and after selecting New>Project>ASP.NET Core Web Application

[image]

I then get a new window 'New ASP.NET Core Web Application' which in my tutorial shows three choices for template but mine is empty.

[image]

There is an option which says 'Get additional project templates' which I did but it just offered a project which I downloaded from GIT called 'Templates-Master'. I don't know how I get this into my templates. I also went to my Installation setup to see if I missed anything but as you can see below it all seems to be there.

[image]

[image]

The problem is without being able to select a template, I can't go any further. My tutorial seems to imply they should be there, what do I do?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your pc?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately made no difference

Comment: Very strange thing! Try reinstalling VS2017 Again and then install the SDKs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the warning and unexpected result, it seems you installed the wrong version of SDK.

Try to install [SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download), choose the right version(x86).

If it still exists, try to check PATH environment variable points to the location in which the SDK is installed. The installer normally sets the PATH.

Reference: [Troubleshoot ASP.NET Core projects](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/test/troubleshoot.md)